# IOS,Tableview Objective C,

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, datasource

There is 5 elements in an array , in that 2 elements have data and another elements are blank and in tableview it show both element but when i scroll the app crash.i have to show **menu_name** in the section and its working but when i scroll tableview the app crash because, so can any one give me the solution?

Here is the Response  which i have to show in tableview

```
 "status":"true",
    "message":"food point menu available",
    "data":[
    {
       "menu_id":"9",
       "menu_name":"Morning Menu",
      "food_list":[
      {
          "food_name":"Brigadeiros",
           "foodtype":"Pastas",
          "food_per_person":"20",
          "food_bonus":"packing"
     },
     {
        "food_name":"Cachaca",
        "foodtype":"Pastas",
        "food_per_person":"30",
        "food_bonus":"packing"
     }
    ]
    },
    {
     "menu_id":"10",
     "menu_name":"Afternoon Menu",
      "food_list":[
        {
             "food_name":"Quindim",
            "foodtype":"Pastas",
           "food_per_person":"30",
           "food_bonus":"packing"
       },
       {
           "food_name":"Cachaca",
           "foodtype":"Pastas",
           "food_per_person":"30",
           "food_bonus":"packing"
       }
    ]
    },
    {
    "menu_id":"12",
    "menu_name":"Evening Menu",
    "food_list":""
    },
    {
    "menu_id":"17",
    "menu_name":"MenuSegundaFeira",
    "food_list":""
    },
    {
    "menu_id":"18",
    "menu_name":"MenuTercaFeira",
    "food_list":""
    }
    ]
    }
```

And this is the code which i have written in my app

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    if([FinalArrayCategory count]>0)    {
        return [[[FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"food_list"] count];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if([FinalArrayCategory count]>0)    {
        return [[FinalArrayCategory valueForKey:@"menu_name"] count];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionName;
    sectionName =[[FinalArrayCategory valueForKey:@"menu_name"] objectAtIndex:section];
    return sectionName;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MenuListCELL *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.lblpice.text=[[[[FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"food_list"] valueForKey:@"food_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //  cell.lblType.text=[[FinalArrayCategory valueForKey:@"category_name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    //    cell.lblBonus.text=[[FinalArrayCategory valueForKey:@"food_bonus"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    //    cell.lblFoodName.text=[[FinalArrayCategory valueForKey:@"menu_name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    //

    //    NSString *pickURL=[[FinalArrayCategory valueForKey:@"food_image"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    //    [cell.lblImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pickURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"itemplaceholder.jpg"] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

    //    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

    //    }];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please show assignment in Your Array

Comment: Start by parsing JSON into objects. Don't work with dictionaries. Don't use `valueForKey:`. Use `objectForKey:` or a subscript.

Comment: It would help to see the output from the debug navigator to help identify the issue. However I personally would be looking at the cellForRowAtIndexPath and would be wrapping some logic around the valueForKey:@"food_name" as I think you'll find this will fail when "food_list" is "" as you don't have a valueForKey food_name. So either add blank values in your food_list for the keys or check whether the keys exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Please try this code..**

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [[[FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"food_list"] count];
    }
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

        return [FinalArrayCategory count];

    }

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        NSString *sectionName;
        sectionName =[[FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"menu_name"];
        return sectionName;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MenuListCELL *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if ([[[FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"food_list"] iskindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dictData=[[[FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"food_list"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblpice.text=[dictData objectForKey:@"food_name"];

    }else{
         cell.lblpice.text=@"";
    }
        return cell;
}
```

And let me know its working or not.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: @Ethan at lease appreciate with the upvote or mark as right answer. :)

Comment: sorry @Ravi i was little bit  busy, but thank for the code and help it help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return [[[FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"food_list"] count];
```

change objectAtIndext from 0 to IndexPath.section

Answer (score -1):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MenuListCELL *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if([FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"food_list"].count>0){

        NSString *foodName =[[[[FinalArrayCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"food_list"] valueForKey:@"food_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if(foodName){

            cell.lblpice.text=foodName;
        }



    }else{
        cell.lblpice.text=@"";

    }


    return cell;
}
```

please try this